# Center orthographic camera on Cannon-es body position

Tags: three.js

) I have a domino game where the user clicks 'start' and my orthographic camera uses tween to scroll to the start domino - applies 3000 torque - and then in the animate function another function tracks which cannon body has the most velocity (aka where the action is happening). a setInterval gets a reference from that function every half second and centers the camera's top, bottom, left and right (TBLF) around that body. My question is about translation - how do i translate the x,y,z of a cannon body into the TBLR to center my orthographic camera? Any help greatly appreciated.